# Select which terminal emulator is opened on shortcut

Tags: default-programs

After inadvertently messing up my system, I find that pressing <kbd>super</kbd> and opening the `terminal` app, opens a different window from the one opened when pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>.

The former looks like this:
[image]

, and is the standard one that I know and love, whereas the latter is:

[image]

I'd like to know, how to bind the keyboard shortcut to the other terminal emulator.

The default terminal emulator is not listed in System >> Details >> Default applications, und under System >> Keyboard >> Shortcuts, one can only specify the shortcut, not which terminal it is, that is to be launched.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, `konsole` was set as the default program once the other was no longer available. I used

`sudo update-alternatives --all`

to reset it to what I was used to. (Thanks @DavidFoerster for the suggestion)